# What is the best way to mirror lots of vertices?

Tags: topology

I got this vertices setup on one side of the blade:
[image]

What is the quickest way to duplicate this vertex setup to the other side, without having to manually do all the loop cuts and try to match the original side? I can't do mirror modifier, because the other side is supposed to be flat

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and unselect the nonmanifold edge loop (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> while hovering the cursor over it). Duplicate the selected vertices (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and scale it along the X axis by 0 (<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>). Finally remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*).
[image]